# PowerShell Quickstart

Tags: powershell

What is the best way you jump-started your Powershell adoption?

What resources, tips, scenarios got you up to speed quickly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptcenter/default.aspx

Massively useful for all forms of scripting. In the past I learned VBScript and WMI through the Script Center, and it now has a lot of useful stuff on Powershell scripting.

JR

Comment: Good link... but a bit Nebulus as well.  Anything that took you from ZERO to 60mph?

Comment: As Doug says below, I found the best approach was to choose a problem. Then search the Script Center for example code and do it. The Powershell language is very simple, it's learning all the useful scriplets and objects supplied by Powershell that takes the time. If you sit down and start coding, with the Script center to hand, you'll be surprised how quickly you pick it up.

Answer (score 13):

**books:**

I would start with this one.

> **[Effective Windows PowerShell: The Free eBook](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6930.entry)**

These two books are more advanced.

> **[Windows PowerShell in Action](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932394907)**
>   A great source of information, the definite reference for PowerShell.
>
> **[Windows PowerShell Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596528493)**
> This Cookbook provides hundreds of tested scripts that you can use right away to administer Windows systems.

Answer (score 7):

Picking specific tasks at work and **forcing** myself to do them in PowerShell instead of in VBS or manually.  No pain, no gain.

Also, the PowerScripting Podcast is a pretty good resource to help you learn even when you aren't actively coding.

Comment: Agree on the specific task part.  But surely you had some tidbit, tool, URL, etc that got it clicking for you.  That's what I'm after...

Comment: Not really - the closest I can come to a "specific tool" is PowerShell In Action.

Comment: +1 This is basically what I'm doing.

Comment: And some videos of Snover that are positively inspiring.  The one with Erik Meijer is great.

Answer (score 3):

Watch the powershell webcasts from the technet events site.
 1- [Introducing Windows PowerShell](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=5637033)

2- [One Cmdlet, Two Cmdlet, Three Cmdlet, Four:](https://www.livemeeting.com/cc/mseventsbmo/view?id=1032313500&role=attend&pw=CCC8C451)

3- [Objects, Objects Everywhere: Working With Objects in Windows PowerShell](https://www.livemeeting.com/cc/mseventsbmo/view?id=1032313503&role=attend&pw=9D3199CE)

4- [New Kid on the Scriptblock: Writing Scripts in Windows PowerShell](https://www.livemeeting.com/cc/mseventsbmo/view?id=1032313975&role=attend&pw=A2B0B03A)

5- [Amazing But True: Things You Never Dreamt You Could Do in Windows PowerShell](https://www.livemeeting.com/cc/mseventsbmo/view?id=1032313506&role=attend&pw=48928A1E)

After watching those for some hands on training you can take the [interactive labcast](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=5889457)
If you don't have an environment to play in you can use the [virtual lab](http://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?EventID=1032314395&EventCategory=3)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Powershell in Action gets my vote for most useful reference book and its very readable. The forums in [powershellcommmunity](http://www.powershellcommunity.org) are useful. Most of the information I've found is from blogs. Here's a partial list of [Powershell blogs](http://halr9000.com/article/698). I'm also a fan of user groups, but do not have one in my area, so I try to attend online. The [Powerscripting Podcast](http://powerscripting.wordpress.com/) and [Virtual Powershell User Group](http://marcoshaw.blogspot.com/) are couple examples of user groups/shows.

As noted you should commit to doing your next project in Powershell to really learn it.

Answer (score 2):

I worked through PowerShell.com's [Master PowerShell eBook](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/). I have a solid background in VBScript and a pretty good understanding of OO concepts, which probably helps as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some good pieces of advice can also be found on [John D Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/software.html#powershell) website.

Answer (score 1):

Review (and use) other people's code.

Three excellent sites for this being:

- The above mentioned, Script Center's [Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/en-us/)
- [PoshCode.org](http://poshcode.org/) - a repository of PowerShell scripts that are free for public use
- The [Hey Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/) blog - at least a script a day answering a specific need

And as a bonus, the most complete [cheat-sheet](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2909895/quadfold) I have found. (Unfortunately, I am not sure if that posting is the original source.)